# How to have an interactive way of drawing lines from a custom selected price?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am wondering if there is a way to write a code that help me to draw lines from custom prices in the following way:

I want to be able to select a price with my mouse and then I have a horizontal line (or ray) be drawn at that price and **also** another line at `x%` of the first line be drawn on the chart.
If possible, I would like to do this several times.i.e. I can do it as many times as I like on any prices.

I would really appreciate it if experts can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `input.price()` with `confirm=true`.

When you add your indicator to the chart, it will ask you to mark a price value. Then you can use the return value of this and calculate +/- 5% or whatever you want.

You need to add as many `input.price()` calls as you need.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

price1 = input.price(0, "Price 1", confirm=true)

price2 = price1 * 1.05
price3 = price1 * 0.95

plot(price1, color=color.yellow)
plot(price2, color=color.green)
plot(price3, color=color.red)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I was looking for.
Do you know how I can display a name on the top of each line? eg addd some note on the top of the line that is drawn

Comment: You can use `label.new()` for that.

Comment: Thanks, can you please suggest a way of making it to be like a Ray instead of line? I want to have a ray from the point that I select moving forward and not have the line in back of that point. would it be possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but please ask a new question for that.